# hide buttons in slider first/last page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to make a slider with the "previous" button disappear when it is on the first slide and the "next" button disappear when it is on the last slide. The format of making the slider is to use php, forms and jscript.

**Here is the HTML** :

```
<form id="formstyle" target="frame" class="formstyle" method="post" action="saveRecord.php">

    <?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  
        $i++;    
    ?>


<div class="imgdiv" <?php if ($i != 1) echo "style='display: none;'" ?>>

    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo "SlideID".$i ?>" value="<?php echo $row['Id'] ?>">    
<input type="hidden" name="noRows" value="<?php echo $rowcount ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $i ?>"> 

    <?php 
      /*  for($a=0; $a<$row)*/
         $imgURL= "images/".$row['folderName']."/".$row['SlideImage'];

    ?>

        <section>
            <div class="sectionsides"></div>

            <div id="imagepage">
                <img id="imgshow" src="<?php echo $imgURL; ?>"><br>
            </div>

            <div class="sectionsides"></div>
        </section>
        <div id="navarea">

            <button id="upimg" type="button" class="button black display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1);">

                <img class="upbutton" src="images/arrow-5.png" alt="logout" />

            </button>

            <article>
                <img class="enter" src="images/text.png">Enter description:
            </article>

            <button id="downimg" type="button" class="button black display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1);">

                <img class="downbutton" src="images/arrow-5.png" alt="logout" />


            </button>

        </div>


        <?php 

    $textvalue="";
    $checkText = "SELECT * FROM user where UserId='".$uid."' AND EventId='".$eid."' AND SpeakerId='".$sid."' AND Speaker_SlideId='".$row['Id']."'";
    $sltText = mysqli_query($con,$checkText) or die(mysqli_error());
    $textRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sltText);

    if(isset($textRow['Text']))
    {
            $textvalue=$textRow['Text'];
    }

        ?>


        <div id="descarea">
            <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="<?php echo "textonly".$i ?>"><?php echo $textvalue; ?> </textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonarea">
            <div class="thebuttons">
            <input type="submit" id="saveThis" value="Save" class="savin"/>
            </div>
            <div class="thebuttons">
            <input type="button" onclick="location.href='templateTextImage.php';" value="View All"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php

        }   

  ?>

</form>
```

**And here is the script:**

```
    var imgpost = 0;
    var count;

    function plusDivs(obj) 
{

        var list = document.getElementsByClassName('imgdiv');           
        console.log(list.length);

        if (obj == 1) {
            if (imgpost == list.length - 1) {
                return;
            }
            list[imgpost].style.display = "none";
            list[++imgpost].style.display = "inline";
            $('.upbutton').hide();

        } else {

            if (imgpost == 0) {
                return;
            }
            list[imgpost].style.display = "none";
            list[--imgpost].style.display = "inline";
            $('.downbutton').hide();
        }   


        //alert ("imgpost="+ imgpost);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =imgpost +1;

        setcookie("TestCookie", 100, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day      
        document.cookie = "count=" + imgpost;
        alert (document.cookie);
    }
```

Without change to a different method is it still possible to create the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use jQuery plugin for slider it provides all built in functionality as you needed. you can hide next, prev. nav using this class in owl carousal.

```
.disabled.owl-next{display:none;}
.disabled.owl-prev{display:none;}
```

**This one is my favorite - https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/**